# pandas aggregate include all groups

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following issue with groupby aggregation, i.e adding groups which are not presented in the dataframe but based on the desired output should be included. An example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""day,sale
1,1
2,4
2,10
4,7
5,2.3
7,4.4
2,3.4""") 
#day 3,6 are intentionally not included here but I'd like to have it in output

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")
df1=df.groupby(['day'])['sale'].agg('sum').reset_index().rename(columns={'sale':'dailysale'})

df1
```

How can I get the following? Thank you!

```
1   1.0
2   17.4
3   0.0
4   7.0
5   2.3
6   0.0
7   4.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with specified `range` after aggregating `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['day'])['sale']
         .sum()
         .reindex(range(1, 8), fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(name='dailysale'))
print (df1)

   day  dailysale
0    1        1.0
1    2       17.4
2    3        0.0
3    4        7.0
4    5        2.3
5    6        0.0
6    7        4.4
```

Another idea is use `ordered categorical`, so aggregate `sum` add missing rows:

```
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=range(1, 8), ordered=True)
df1 = df.groupby(['day'])['sale'].sum().reset_index(name='dailysale')
print (df1)
  day  dailysale
0   1        1.0
1   2       17.4
2   3        0.0
3   4        7.0
4   5        2.3
5   6        0.0
6   7        4.4
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I liked thugh your 2nd option (before edit!! ) because in my case could be that exactly the day1 is missing, so putting that will lead to missing that day. if I specify by hand, it is safer.

Comment: @physiker - OK, add to answer.

Comment: just a quick question: how can I specificly say reindex for the day column? because in my case I have several level of groupby and with your tip, pandas seems to get confused with index reindex ....

Comment: @physiker - try parameter `axis=0, level=1` add to reindex, but generally is necessary create new MultiIndex.